# xbox kinetic sensor and adopter

Tags: kinect, xbox

i am about to start developmnet on sensor using xbox sensor.

plaing to buy https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/d/Kinect-Sensor-for-Xbox-One/91HQ5578VKSC  sensot. want to know two things

is this the right adopter to use with this device https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/d/kinect-adapter-for-xbox-one-s-and-windows-pc/933z2vkmthcs/k5nz or any other adopter?

any other device needed to start developing interactive motion sensor apps.?

any body have any starting app on gitub for reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct adapter required for connecting Kinect with the PC for data acquisition. For starting development, the examples that come with the Kinect SDK are quite good and sufficient, especially if you are going for C++ or C#.

For github, just search for [Kinect](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Kinect&type=) and there are quite a few developers that are actively updating their applications, however, without any detail regarding what you want to do and in what language, any example will be rather pointless.